# Load new detailview in

Tags: ios, uitableview, uisplitviewcontroller

Ive created a new splitview from xcode 4.5. I've changed the Master view table to a static table (3-rows). How do I load different views when each row is clicked into the detailed area?

I believe it needs to be done here:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //load new view here
}
```

but Im not sure of the syntax.

Comment: If using storyboards, the easiest way is to create replace segues. Just specify the detail as the destination for the target of the replacement. If you need to invoke these segues programmatically, do `performSegueWithIdentifier`.

Comment: If you had created using the existing template, it should be easy, infact the code should already be there. Even other wise, try to create another project and then choose "Master/detail" as a template and you will be able to learn every thing you want there. The template will default to "Core Data", and it is some times better to go that route, since it will teach you a lot more.

Comment: @Srikanth - This is the code thats in the above function, it doesnt help me.

    `if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        NSManagedObject *object = [[self fetchedResultsController] objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        self.detailViewController.detailItem = object;
    }`

Comment: @Rob - I am using storyboards. I dont want to just replace the original, because I have 3 possible views that I want to load. A different one for each row selected. So I guess my question is more complicated then I first assumed. How would I connect the 3 new views to the selected rows?

Comment: I don't understand you when you say "I don't want to replace the original". So what do you want to happen to the original when you bring in one of the three? I don't get what you're saying.

Comment: When editing your storyboard, you can control-drag from each of the three tableview cells to the appropriate scene for that tableview. Make the segue a "replace" segue, that replaces the "details" view.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIViewController *vc = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"nameOfYourFile.xib"];
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

There are a lot of ways to do it but here is a way to show a modal view controller in your 
didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

If you are using a navigation controller you might use:

```
UIViewController *vc = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"nameOfYourFile.xib"];
[self pushViewController:vc animated:YES];
```

EDIT:  I may have misunderstood your question, now that I re-read it.  What do you mean by the detailed area?

Comment: I think he's talking about the right-side of UISplitViewController

Comment: Yes, the right side, sorry the proper name would be, Detail View Contorller

Comment: Im using storyboards, not .xib

Answer (score 0):

Theres a downloadable example project here:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=1546